# SQLITE: SELECT between timestamps doesnt work

Tags: javascript, sqlite

my goal is it to search between two time stamps of a certain time span  all of this is stored in an array of an dynamic amount of time stamps depending on how much days i want to search in the past. Originally they looked like that `2020-07-30T08:41:22.164Z` but i removed the unimportant parts of it and now it looks like that `07-30`. So i just filtered the time stamp to its month and day. Now to my problem: I am trying to bring that command to work: `"SELECT status FROM database WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN '%datesStored[datesStored.length -1]%' AND '%datesStored[0]%'"`.
Ignore the fact that i used JS where the time stamps should be. The whole SQLite statement is in fact a String I've built that i am trying to send to SQLite node in nore-red. But that is not important. They only thing i need is the certain command that would work.
Thank you for any responses.

```js
var datesSaved = msg.payload;
var daysBack = global.get("maxDaysBack");
var min = datesSaved[0];
var max = datesSaved[datesSaved.length-1];

msg.topic = "SELECT status, dateTime FROM database WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '%07-28%' AND '%07-29%';";

msg.labels = msg.payload;
msg.payload = [];
return msg;
```

Comment: You should probably use the entire timestamp string format rather than trying to a substring search. Also greater than and less than would work just fine.

Comment: What is the actual timestamp range for which you are trying to search?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It depends. But the higher date is always today, because i want to see all datasets from today into the past, lets say like 7 days into the past. So from 07-23 to 07-30.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter out certain data in an array using a time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225838/filter-out-certain-data-in-an-array-using-a-time-stamp)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your search strategy is here, but if you want to see all records going back 7 days to the past, you may use:

```
SELECT status, dateTime
FROM database
WHERE dateTime >= date('now', '-7 day');
```